# Pre-cache Android views?

Tags: android, user-interface

This question has been asked several times already but I'd like to bring it up again. I am using a popup window to display another part of my app. The user will open it every now and then so it makes sense to keep the delay between clicking and displaying as low as possible. Depending on system load it takes between 10 and 70ms to display. The popup itself is being initialized before (it basically generates 50 buttons) and the only thing a button click triggers is

```
public void initiateRemixWindow() {
        rwindo.showAtLocation(remixGrid, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```

whereas rwindow is a `PopupView` and remixGrid is a TableLayout. Everything else, the table, the buttons, ... is being done before so the only task I want to get done as quick as possible is displaying the popup.

I achieved better results (in terms of time) by just `hide()`ing all the UI elements but I would consider this terrible code and also I - except the lack of a `hide()` function - really like the handling of a `PopupView`.

Is there anything else I can do to display the popup faster? Or is there any workarounds that you usually "fall" for?

Comment: Why is 70ms too slow? Most users wouldn't even notice...

Comment: it is a music app and 70ms is awful in this field

Comment: You might get better answers if you update your question to describe the *actual* problem (which I'm guessing is the delay in producing a sound when something is pressed, rather than how long it takes to display a view).

Comment: Sorry but as far as I remember I was the one posting the question above so I'd be kinda surprised if you knew more about it than I do.